# How to pass a locator as a parameter on PageObject function using playwright?

Tags: python, playwright-python

I made BasePage class with a function enter_text that takes 2 arguments: locator of a field and text which fills that field

```
class BasePage:
    def __init__(self, page):
        self.page = page

    def open_page(self, url):
        self.page.goto(url)

    def enter_text(self, locator, text):
        locator.fill(text)
```

Class Login inherits from BasePage

```
class Login(BasePage):
    URL = 'http://example.com/auth/login/'
    login_locator = ???
    password_locator = ???

    def login(self, login, password):
        self.open_page(self.URL)
        self.enter_text(self.login_locator, login)
        self.enter_text(self.password_locator, password)
        self.press_key_on_field(self.password_label, 'Enter')
```

The test itself is

```
def test_login_success(page: Page):
    new_page = Login(page)
    Login.login(new_page, 'admin', 'admin')
    Login.is_login_success(new_page)
```

where page is default playwright fixture

How should I set `login_locator` and `password_locator` variables in class Login?
Maybe it won't work at all and there is another way to implement Page-Object Model using playwright?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this in the Login class:

```
def __init__(self, page):
    super().__init__(page)
    self.login_locator = page.locator("Some locator")
```